# Alteryx Rtool giving output failure

Tags: r, alteryx

I am trying to output my wilcox test on Alteryx Rtool, but I am not suceeding. It appears a failure: "Error: R (12): Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : "

It runs OK on "R", but on Alteryx Rtool it appears this message. I run line per line and it is on the last line. The output.

Below is the code:

````
data <- read.Alteryx("#1")

#Verificar se o campo P-value está preenchido ou não
#Se for diferente de vazio está preenchido
if (data$p.value != '') {
Week1 <- read.Alteryx("#2")
 "&" 
Week2 <- read.Alteryx("#3")
}

Week1 <- as.data.table(Week1)
Week2 <- as.data.table(Week2)

# TESTE DE MANN WHITNEY (Variance Test for Non-Normal)

Week1_data <- Week1$Wk1_feature_value
Week2_data <- Week2$Wk2_feature_value

#define vectors
week1 <- c(Week1_data)
week2 <- c(Week2_data)

merge(cbind(week1, X=1:length(week1)),
      cbind(week2, X=1:length(week2)), all.y =T)[-1]



# TESTE DE MANN WHITNEY (Variance Test for Non-Normal)
variance_wilcox<- wilcox.test(week1,week2, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)

write.Alteryx(variance_wilcox, 1)``` **This last Line is the problem. The output.**
````

Comment: "The output." ... is not a complete English sentence. It is not possible to tell what is happening. Furthermore those of us familiar with R may not be familiar with Alteryx. Is it a proprietary program? Free?

Comment: `wilcox.test` returns a `list` structure.  Please check what the requirement for `write.Alteryx` function

Comment: Try after converting to a tibble/data.frame structure i.e. `variance_wilcox <- broom::tidy(variance_wilcox)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun. You gave me a precious tip to found the solution.

Comment: Below the solution:
variance_wilcox<- wilcox.test(week1,week2, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95)
variance_test <- tibble(variance_wilcox)
variance_test[] <- lapply(variance_test, as.character)
write.Alteryx(variance_test, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after converting to a tibble/data.frame structure i.e.

```r
variance_wilcox <- broom::tidy(variance_wilcox)
```

Below the solution:

```
variance_wilcox <- wilcox.test(week1,week2, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95) 
variance_test <- tibble(variance_wilcox) 
variance_test[] <- lapply(variance_test, as.character) 
write.Alteryx(variance_test, 1)
```

Thanks to @akrun